# What are common parameters for the Eriksen flanker task?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, experimental-psychology, attention, executive-function

I'm looking to create a flanker task for an upcoming experiment. I'm wondering if there are any papers/websites that outline what the "standard" flanker task contains?

Specifically, I'm trying to find some information on the most commonly used number of trials/blocks, what the experimental manipulations are (besides congruency), or timings of the stimuli

Of course there's some variability to this, and it would likely change depending on the research question, but even just a range of values that I should work within would be useful

Comment: Hello and welcome to Cognitive Sciences! Will you please provide the results of your initial research? Thank you!